EPERM: Operation not Permitted issue while doing yarn start in react native
Click here to see image
While I was doing yarn start in react native I am constantly getting this EPERM issue in terminal. There is another thing...while doing yarn android then node window opens...and in terminal the initialization goes 100%, configuring goes 100%, and during Executing suddenly the node window closes and in terminal the executing goes to 100% and shows build successful and terminal closes. I have tried many times but I am getting the same issue

delete the node_modules/ folder and reinstall it. and you can check to folder permissions.
